# How can I add objects with multiple values to an array?

Tags: javascript, html

**Hi, How do i add 2 values from 2 different user inputs as one object to an array?**

This is my current code, it doesn't do it,instead it adds the values as seperate objects, not one with 2 values like the object already in the array

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>W3.CSS</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">

<script>
function main(){
 let a = prompt('enter a number');
 let b = prompt('enter a name');
let data = [{name:'Joe', number:6}];
data.push(a,b);
console.log(data);
}
main();
</script>

<button onclick = "main()"> click </button>
</html>
```

Comment: `data.push( {name:b, number:a} )`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Corrected your code. You were pushing name and number as an individual item to the Array. Just push an object (used object notation for object {}) of name and number keys.

```js
const data = [{ name: "Joe", number: 6 }];

console.log(data);

function main() {
  let a = prompt("enter a number");
  let b = prompt("enter a name");

  data.push({ name: b, number: Number(a) });
  
  console.clear()
  console.log(data);
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height:100% !important; top:0; left:40% !important; width:60%; }
.as-console-row         { background-color: #87f1f1; }
.as-console-row::after  { display:none !important; }
.as-console-row::before { content:'data='; font-size:.9em; }
```

```html
<button onclick="main()">add values to data array</button>
```